# Ios Development Codename one : Entering values in the Text Field of Gridview

Tags: android, ios, codenameone

how to enter values in text field of Gridview / Table like holder in android.. i have tried lot of models but nothing is working .. please help me to do enter values in gridview with textfield listeners

Answer (score 0):

There are both the `Table` component and the `TableLayout` that allows you to place arbitrary component in a grid structure.

Comment: but i can't get the view of the particular textfield or label values in the custom grid structure

Comment: I suggest phrasing the question more clearly ideally with code you tried and code you would expect to work. In a Table you would override the createCell method to get the Component instances or customize them. In a TableLayout you can just add any component you want in a table like structure.